# Error while Integrating Apache Nutch 2.3 with Hbase 0.94.14 and Solr 5.2.1

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, solr

I am integrating Nutch with Hbase and Solr.

After starting Hadoop and Hbase services, I run following command in Nutch Home

`sudo -E bin/crawl urls/seed.txt TestCrawl http://localhost:8983/solr/ 2`

I am facing these errors:

```
Injecting seed URLs
/usr/local/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject urls/seed.txt -crawlId TestCrawl
InjectorJob: starting at 2016-05-26 15:41:14
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls/seed.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:114)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:218)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 10 more
Error running:
  /usr/local/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject urls/seed.txt -crawlId TestCrawl
Failed with exit value 1.
```

Can anyone suggest me what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Nutch, It is unable to locate a transitive dependency while executing the crawl script.

Better configuration to use is nutch-2.3.1 with hbase-0.98.8-hadoop2

for better understanding refer given below url

**https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial**

this is a bug in gora-hbase 0.6.1

In addition add the missing hbase-common-0.98.8-hadoop2.jar transitive dependency, this is a bug in gora-hbase 0.6.1

```
 <dependency org="org.apache.hbase" name="hbase-common" rev="0.98.8-hadoop2" conf="*->default" />
```

**With this i was able to crawl successfully.**